# Можно ли использовать placeholder в string array android?

Tags: android, строки

У меня есть массив строковых ресурсов, элементы которого имеют placeholder я добавил их туда по такому же принципу что и в обычном ресурсе и думал что смогу поменять значение так же просто как и в обычной строке, но я почему то не могу получить доступ к отдельному айтему и не могу понять как это сделать. Вот [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656371/dynamic-string-using-string-xml) по placeholder который я нашел в enSO и [вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19408194/android-how-do-you-access-a-string-array-from-strings-xml-in-a-custom-class) что я нашел по массиву. Вроде все понятно расписано но я не могу динамически поменять значение. Вот у меня массив:

```
<string-array name="array">
<item>Все %1$d текст.</item>
<item>Все %1$d текст.</item>
</string-array>
```

я думал дать айтему имя, но сразу встает вопрос как к отдельному айтему получить доступ.